# Install old library file required by a program

Tags: shared-library

I have a program that requires libreadline6. But I only have libreadline5 and libreadline7. I tried to install version 6 of the library but I cannot do this. A message comes up that the package is not available. The message goes on to say the library has been obsoleted or is only available from another source.
I could try and use one of the other versions through a link but which one should I use? 
Any help would be appreciated. -Peter

Comment: You may be able to get away with a simple symlink. What is the result of: `sudo find /lib -iname libreadline*` ? My suspicion is that one result will be `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.7.0` in which case the following may be useful: `cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu && sudo ln -sv libreadline.so.7.0 libreadline.so.6`

Comment: Thanks I created a link to version 7 and it seems to work.

Comment: Great news! I have converted the 'comment' into a formal answer and hopefully you will have the time to 'Accept' the answer as a successful one by clicking on the 'check' mark next to the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than download and install a point upgrade or downgrade of a specific library you can often simply make a symbolic link, commonly known as a symlink, from the required library to the point upgrade library.

In your case the most common location for the libreadline shared libraries will be `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.7.0` although this can be tested by running the following:

```
sudo find /lib -iname libreadline*
```

If this is the case the following two commands will successfully create a symlink to libreadline.so.7.0:

```
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -sv libreadline.so.7.0 libreadline.so.6
```

And then hopefully all will be well...

**References:**

- [libreadline.so.6 required but libreadline.so.7 is the current version, build fails #993](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/993): A neat illustration of the required syntax from somebody caught in the same dilemma as yourself :)

Comment: You can create a symbolic link but that doesn't mean that works. 
A different library version MAY be compatible but more likely it will not, in worst case with catastrophic results